# iframe dynamic height (no access to javascript or stylesheets)

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm in a really bad spot as I need to make an iframes height flexible accordingly to its content, but I don't have access to any stylesheets nor the head on the server. I'm also not aloud to use any JavaScript.

Comment: when you say the head on the server you mean you can't put a `<style>` in the `<head>` section of the html file?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm working in a terrrible CMS and I'm not allowed any more access than that :(

Comment: can you set the style directly in the `<iframe>` using the `style` property? So like: `<iframe style="height: auto;">`

Comment: Yes I can add style tags to any property within the body tag, but not the actual body tag. <iframe style="height: auto;"> dooesn't work btw.

Comment: Do you have access to both the content of the iframe and the iframe itself?

Comment: Yes I have full access to the content of the iframe itself as it's hosted on my server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with inline CSS alone.  The best you could probably do is set a fixed height on the iframe that is greater than that of the content being called.

There are javascript solutions for this if you have access to both pages and they both exist on the same domain, but other than that I think you are out of luck.

Ajax would be another solution, but it would again require javascript.

Comment: I actually use ajax calls in the content of the iframe. It's because of those I needed a flexible solution as the height differs depending on the content being fetched.